# Achartengine repaint

Tags: android, charts, android-linearlayout, repaint, achartengine

I have one data connection in webservice. In Assynctask i get data every 5 second.
After the data arrived i make new dataset and becuse the mChartView living i just repaint. And here comming my problem. The Line chart repaint not regenerate the chart just make one new top of the last. And of course 2-3 minutes out of menmory :(

Here my code:

```
class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    private ArrayList<String> Alldata = new ArrayList<String>();
    public XYMultipleSeriesDataset datasetOut;
    public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRendererOut;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        Alldata.clear();
        Alldata = DataFromWeb.getChartDataNew("&name=XXX", "XXX");

        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {


        datasetOut = CCChart.getDataSet(getBaseContext(), Alldata);
        mRendererOut = CCChart.getRendererPortrait(getBaseContext());


        Log.d("Debug", "alldatasize: " + Alldata.size());
        Log.d("Debug", "dataset " + datasetOut.getSeriesCount() );

        if (mChartView != null) {
            mChartView.repaint();

            Log.v("CC_trace", "CCChartRepaint");

        } else {

            mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), datasetOut , mRendererOut);

                layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, getHeight()));

                Log.v("CC_trace", "CCChartGenerate");   

        }




    }



}
```

MAybe im not call in good place the repaint() :)

Chart Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxhK6.png)

thx the help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In mine I never call repaint. I just recreate the old one

so like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

    datasetOut = CCChart.getDataSet(getBaseContext(), Alldata);
    mRendererOut = CCChart.getRendererPortrait(getBaseContext());

    Log.d("Debug", "alldatasize: " + Alldata.size());
    Log.d("Debug", "dataset " + datasetOut.getSeriesCount() );

    mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), datasetOut , mRendererOut);

    layout.removeAllViews();
    layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, getHeight()));
    Log.v("CC_trace", "CCChartGenerate");   
}
```